# Designing a method/class to support configurable number of queries with variable number of arguments

Tags: design-patterns, variadic-functions

I have to fire a set of queries(say N, which is decided at run time from DB).

Each query Qi, will have a few variables with in it(say V1, V2...Vj). Input will be provided in the form of Key,Value pair.

Result of these queries will be key value pair which I have to return.

Ex.

```
select * from t where a="ME";
```

PS: This is just an example. I am not firing DB queries.

I was planning to pass query as string parameter with some place-holders for variables and passing a map for KEY-VALUE pairs which will be used to substitute(KEY name will be used to identify placeholder).

Input query for above ex.

```
String query = select * from VRIABLE_FROM_TABLE where a=VARIABLE_WHERE_1;
```

Query string will also be taken from DB.

Input Map will be:

```
FROM_TABLE->t
WHERE_1->"ME"
```

Am I missing something? Any object oriented issue?

What is best way to design this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try implementing the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern): define a common interface for your Commands and have a command executor be responsible for calling the Commands.

In doing so, you can have an arbitrary number of Commands, since the command executor can receive a collection of classes implementing the Command interface; additionally, the executor is decoupled from the contents of the Commands which can be separately instantiated with the needed number of arguments.